# How to add subject line when sending email output of find using ssmtp

Tags: shell, find, cron, ssmtp

I got a script running (as cronjob) that will list the files in a folder before doing a Rsync job and emailing me the list. How can I add a subject line.

```
find /path/to/folder/ -type f -size +1M -name "*.mov" -printf "%f\n" | ssmtp my_email@domain.com
```

I tried this with -s "Subject" but no luck. It only works if I put the subject in a text file and call this text file

```
find /path/to/folder/ -type f -size +1M -name "*.mov" -printf "%f\n" | my_email@domain.com < /path/to/file/subjectline.txt
```

But than it won't add the search results in the Message.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong,

Bas

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
{
    echo To: my_email@domain.com
    echo From: from_email@example.com
    echo Subject: mov files greater than 1M
    echo
    find /path/to/folder/ -type f -size +1M -name "*.mov"
} | ssmtp my_email@domain.com
```

You don't need the `printf` on `find`.

Comment: Awesome that works really well. The only reason I had the -printf "%f\n" was to trim of the full path and just have the filenames. Thank you very much that was really helpful.